# Dynamic String Format C#

Tags: c#, string, dynamic, format, prepend

In C#, Windows Form, how would I accomplish this:

---

```
07:55 Header Text:  This is the data<br/>07:55 Header Text:  This is the data<br/>07:55 Header Text:  This is the data<br/>
```

---

So, as you can see, i have a return string, that can be rather long, but i want to be able to format the data to be something like this:

---

```
<b><font color="Red">07:55 Header Text</font></b>:  This is the data<br/><b><font color="Red">07:55 Header Text</font></b>:  This is the data<br/><b><font color="Red">07:55 Header Text</font></b>:  This is the data<br/>
```

---

As you can see, i essentially want to prepend `<b><font color="Red">` to the front of the header text & time, and append `</font></b>` right before the : section.

So yeah lol i'm kinda lost.

I have messed around with **.Replace()** and **Regex** patterns, but not with much success.  I dont really want to REPLACE text, just append/pre-pend at certain positions.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Note: the [] tags are actually <> tags, but i can't use them here lol

Comment: Please format the question properly

Comment: I'm sorry, i do not understand.  I had asked the question in the post.

Comment: OOOOH!  That's what he meant.  I'm very sorry, i'm very new to this site, and not sure how that all works.  Sorry again, and didn't mean to cause a fuss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you're using RegEx doesn't mean you have to replace text.

The following regular expression:

```
(\d+:\d+.*?:)(\s.*?\[br/\])
```

Has two 'capturing groups.' You can then replace the entire text string with the following:

```
[b][font color="Red"]\1[/font][/b]\2
```

Which should result in the following output:

```
[b][font color="Red"]07:55 Header Text:[/font][/b] This is the data[br/]
[b][font color="Red"]07:55 Header Text:[/font][/b] This is the data[br/]
[b][font color="Red"]07:55 Header Text:[/font][/b] This is the data[br/]
```

**Edit:** Here's some C# code which demonstrates the above:

```
var fixMe = @"07:55 Header Text: This is the data[br/]07:55 Header Text: This is the data[br/]07:55 Header Text: This is the data[br/]";
var regex = new Regex(@"(\d+:\d+.*?:)(\s.*?\[br/\])");
var matches = regex.Matches(fixMe);

var prepend = @"[b][font color=""Red""]";
var append = @"[/font][/b]";

string outputString = "";
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    outputString += prepend + match.Groups[1] + append + match.Groups[2] + Environment.NewLine;
}

Console.Out.WriteLine(outputString);
```

Comment: hum, i'm not familiar with the \2\3 format.  Are those returning results?  Sorry, still new when it comes to the advanced features of regex in C#.

Comment: @user674311 - Sorry, was using a great text editor, Sublime Text, to test out the regex first. The slashes are syntax specific to that editor. However, I've added some C# code which should work to do the same thing.

Comment: OMG that was awesome.  It worked like a charm!  Now i understand some more.  Especially how to do the replaces in there, and i wasn't aware of the 'match' statement.  Thank you so very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `.Insert()` check [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0100__String/AppendstringandinsertstringtoaStringBuilder.htm).

Comment: Aye, but the issue i have is that the .Insert() requires a finite start, right?  like:  MyString.Insert(0, "My"); would insert at position 0.  The problem that I have, unfortunately, is that i need to inserat at various positions, all on one string.  So i'm unsure how to do that w/ .Insert().  Would i need to split the string to an array, and process each line in the array, and then join the array back together first?

Comment: Sorry, I read the unformatted question, hence I gave this to you, thinking you want to append plain text. My bad. The answer given is pure awesomeness !

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way probably is to use `string.Replace()` and `string.Split()`. Say your input string is `input` (untested):

```
var output = string.Join("<br/>", in
    .Split("<br/>)
    .Select(l => "<b><font color=\"Red\">" + l.Replace(": ", "</font></b>: "))
    .ToList()
    ) + "<br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a style and setting the css class of each line by wrapping each line in a `p` or `div` tag?

Easier to maintain and to construct.